# Android Open Activity And Close Previous One

Tags: java, android, android-intent, flags, root

Alright so I have a loader screen which fetches files and what not, things the app needs to function and then when it's done loading it starts the main activity. However when you press back it goes back to the loading activity which obviously i don't want.

Solution I set this in the manifest android:noHistory="true" for the loading screen activity. But there is an issue with this, my application is a root app so it needs superuser permissions in the loader screen and when the su dialog appears asking to accept or decline the loading screen closes since history is off and another app has taken the view. I have found that if i remove noHistory from the manifest su doesn't close my app so i know that's what it is.

So the final question then is, is there a flag or something i can set on the intent to keep the loader out of history when the intent is launched at the end after we've gained superuser permissions cause i need to keep the loader open when superuser comes up but don't want it there when the user hits back

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finish the activity after starting the new one.

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: ha dunno why i never thought that very simple solution thanks a ton