# Closing my Android app in my main activity on back pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities:

A: a Splash Screen

B: the Main activity

When the application starts, I show the splash screen with a short video then call B. I want the user to be able to close application with the back button in activity B. (The user shouldn't see splash screen again.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set android:noHistory="true" for the splash screen in the manifest. This will not add the activity to the back stack.

```
<activity
    android:name="SplashScreen"
    android:noHistory="true"
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your splash screen call finish() when you start Activity B.

Comment: is there any way? 

sometimes I have call home activity when on back pressed.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790222/android-history-stack-clear-without-one

Comment: just call finish() in your splashscreen activity, right after you launched your B activity. The splashscreen activity will be terminated.